# SQL query with dynamic WHERE timestamp

Tags: php, sql, sql-timestamp

How can i get this part of a query to fetch the values by timerange?

Example of a table:

```
  select * from tablename where timeregister between '2017-01-11' And '2017-01-30';
```

How could i get the timeregister to be last 7 days?
I was trying this:

```
select * from tablename where timeregister(NOW(), timeregister) <= 7;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query uses product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
<?php 
    $s_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $e_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+7 days'));
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timeregister, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "'.$s_date.'" AND "'.$e_date.'"';
?>
```

Comment: This was partly working .Getting result for query but the result is equal to 1 day. Looks lik its not fetching the strtotime.

Comment: the date format of saved value in database is like `2017-01-11`...?

Comment: Example of timeregister collum : 2017-01-11 12:20:04+01

Comment: Updated... Try now...

Comment: was able to get it to work by using this:SELECT * FROM table WHERE timeregister >= now() - INTERVAL  '6 days';

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE timeregister >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Was trying this and it was not working. Returned:  syntax error at or near "10". The type is the timeregister  collumn is "timestamp with time zone"

Comment: @Slistryko Try `WHERE (timeregister > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MSSQL or MYSQL? If its MSSQL then you can use the DATEADD function. See script below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timeregister between DATEADD(DD,-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```